# Can't use react-input-mask in strict mode

Tags: javascript, reactjs, web, reactive

Im trying to use [react-input-mask](https://github.com/sanniassin/react-input-mask), but having no success, I can't type anything. I was getting an error related to React Strict mode, but solved it with [Ref Fowarding](https://reactjs.org/docs/forwarding-refs.html#forwarding-refs-to-dom-components). Now I see no errors, but still can't get any input from keyboard, what am I doing wrong ?I'm using a functional component This is my code:

```
 import InputMask from "react-input-mask";


     const InputMasked = React.forwardRef((props, ref) => (
        <InputMask
          placeholder="Digite seu nome"
          className="register-input"
          mask="99/99/9999"
          value={name}
          onChange={(e) => setName(e.target.value)}
          type="text"
        />
      ));
    
      const ref = React.createRef();
    
                <InputMasked
              placeholder="Digite seu nome"
              className="register-input"
              mask="99/99/9999"
              value={name}
              onChange={(e) => setName(e.target.value)}
              type="text"
              ref = {ref}
            />
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This works for me:

```
import InputMask from 'react-input-mask';

export default class TestApp extends React.Component {
    inputMask;
    render() {
        return (
            <InputMask mask="99/99/9999" ref={this.inputMask} />
        )
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The same issue here. I tried lots of things also solved. But not reliably. For that, I made a package for my needs. Maybe It'll be helpful to someone.

https://www.npmjs.com/package/@mahiraltinkaya/react-masked-input